# How to use a ServiceBus Trigger with a topic/subscription in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-functions

I'd like to create an Azure Function that is triggered when a new message is added to a topic/subscription.

For the moment I've created an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/) using the  **ServiceBusQueueTrigger C# Template** and I've set the Queue Name to

```
topicPath + "/Subscriptions/" + subscriptionName
```

[image: Azure Functions ServiceBusQueueTrigger C# Template]

But I've got this exception:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus: Cannot get entity 'topic-test/Subscriptions/subscription-test' because it is not of type **QueueDescription**. Check that you are using method(s) with the correct entity type. System.Runtime.Serialization: Error in line 1 position 1762. Expecting element 'QueueDescription' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect'.. Encountered 'None' with name '', namespace ''. .

[image: Failed to create ServiceBusTrigger with Topic/Subscription in an Azure Function]

I thought the Azure Function was using the [MessagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh322642.aspx) to initialize the message pump but not.

Is there any support for topic/subscription for the moment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes topics are supported, but our UI and templates are behind on that unfortunately - we'll be releasing some updates soon addressing these issues.

For now, you can use the Advanced Editor to edit your trigger binding directly. There you can specify your `subscriptionName` and `topicName` values. Here's an example:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "in",
      "subscriptionName": "subscription-test",
      "topicName": "topic-test",
    }
  ]
}
```

In general, since Azure Functions is build atop the WebJobs SDK, our various bindings are mapped directly to their SDK counterparts. For example `serviceBusTrigger` maps to [ServiceBusTriggerAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/ServiceBusTriggerAttribute.cs) which has `SubscriptionName`/`TopicName` properties. Therefore, expect to see the same properties in the Function metadata model.

Comment: Awesome ! So It should be the same if I want to use a sendGrid binding ? Anyway I'm gonna try.

Comment: We haven't pulled SendGrid into Functions yet. You're the second person that has asked though, so we should do it soon :) We have that issue tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/132

Comment: Should I create a new issue in the webjob sdk: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues?